# how can Ireset auto increment field values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some fields, one of them is an `auto_increment` field after a certain time some records deleted and  field value seuquence is something like , 1,4, 5, 6, ....
how can I reset this field that it starts again from 1 and other record re-ordered
this mean after that my field should be 1,2,3,4,5 ....

Comment: You can unload the data, drop the table, recreate the table and reinsert the data without the `auto_increment field.

Comment: This is a frequent request from beginners but its an aestethic issue and should be left alone.The primary key purpose is to have a "growing" field different from all other values,if they are contigous or not its irrelevant.Nevermind you could mess up if you have foreign keys referring this column.

Comment: @Jens I guest that solution,I ask here for better solution.tnx for your attention

Comment: @Mihai it is not primary or foreign key yet,it just alone table without any realation

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
ALTER TABLE [your_table] AUTO_INCREMENT=x
```

Just replace `[your_table]` with the actual name of the table to be modified, and the "x" with the next expected value in your table: for instance, if your current value is 46, just replace "x" with 47

Comment: I know this command, it restart auto_incerement number after exist value,it means if I have 5 data before, 1,4,5,7,88 , then try this line another new record will have 'x' value, but I want reorder(reassign) exist data

Comment: In this case, create a new table `table2` with the same structure as your initial `table`. Do your SELECT from `table` and INSERT results in `table2` (this should give you an ordered PK), then delete `table` and rename `table2` to `table`.